# In which directory is shell source code and executable present?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Linux, in which directory  is the source code and executable of (bash) shell present ?

I thought I will do `which cd` then see the output and find out where the shell is because cd is a builtin and its location would be location of the source code. But below is the output:

```
-bash-4.1$ which cd
/usr/bin/which: no cd in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)
-bash-4.1$
```

So could you please tell me how to find out where the in the file system is shell present normally in Linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `which` command does not know about shell builtins. According to the manpage `which(1)`, it "[searches] the PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments".

On my distribution (Debian) and many others, `which bash` gives the following output:

```
/bin/bash
```

The `type` command on the other hand gives the following output, when called as `type cd`:

```
cd is a shell builtin
```

As far as the source code is concerned, it is not installed by default in many distributions. On Debian, for example, you can retrieve it via `apt-get source bash`, or more generally, you can get the upstream sources at [gnu.org](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

Comment: Ohk. So i saw, bash elf file is there, but no source code i guess. Thanks.